# jQuery toggle on sublements populated by Ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I have some json file which populates the page with some info.
On the populated elements I need to run a toggle operation but I cannot retrieve the subelement in jquery.

```
function() {
  $.getJSON( "/pathto/glossar.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      items.push( "<dt>" + key + "</dt>\n\r<dd id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</dd>\n\r\n\r" );
    });
    $( "<dl/>", {
      "id": "glossar",
      html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "#main-container" ).on(
        $("dt").click(function() {
            $(this).children().toggle()
        })
        //$('dd').hide()  
    );
  });
}
```

The generated DOM elements are

```
<dl id="glossar">
<dt>KEY</dt>
<dd id="KEY">Bla Bla Value</dd>
..
</dl>
```

I need to toogle on the dd values once the dt is clicked. Looks like the jquery .on does not fetch DDs in this case!? Is there a need for a second .on on dt-s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding dynamically your elements you have to use event delegation with jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

Ref:

> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest,
>   innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur
>   all the way up to the body and the document element. In Internet
>   Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not
>   natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create
>   consistent cross-browser behavior.
>
> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

You can define one handler in `document.ready`, so outside your ajax call like:

```
$("body").on("click", "#main-container dt", function () {
    $(this).siblings("dd").toggle();
});
```

For the HTML provided the `dd` element it's a sibling of `dt` not a children, so I changed the selector accordingly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/EFb4X/

Comment: Thanks for the info and code: 

 $(this).siblings("dd").toggle();
Will toggle any "dd". Need only the children.  $(this).children("dd").toggle(); is not working ...

Comment: Just realized that dt/dd is not parent children relation. dt has no children.

Comment: Is working fine see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EFb4X/1/; yep ar not parent/children, but siblings

Comment: Any alternative help to access the "dd" which has for ID the value of "this" selector?

Comment: @Armand the current code is not ok for you? Can you explain better?

Comment: Irvin thx for the code and explanations, great help! Had another question related to the fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/EFb4X/4/ Need to toggle only the DD with same ID as the the value of the clicked selector. Any advice how to achieve it?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I think is better ask another question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46151/discussion-between-armand-and-irvin-dominin-aka-edward)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
 in getjson function write following code,

```
$( "<dl/>", {
  "id": "glossar",
  html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "#main-container" );
```

And in document ready i.e after $.getjson write your  click

```
$("dt").click(function() {
    $(this).children('dd').toggle();
});
```

Comment: The click function is invoked but no children is found, no toggle... Same as above

Comment: @armand make it a live click as

$("dt").live('click', function() {
    $(this).children('dd').toggle();
});

Comment: @armand then you can use .on function like this

$(document).on('click', 'dt', function() { $(this).children('dd').toggle(); });